# Left outer join doesn't use keys on inverting join order

Tags: mysql, left-join

As you can see both the tables have identical structure but one left outer join uses keys and the other one doesn't and hence the performance is way too poor in the second case. Any explanation why would the second left join not use keys?

```
mysql> show create table t1;
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                          |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t1    | CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `certificateNo` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `certificateNo` (`certificateNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show create table t2;
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                             |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| t2    | CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `certificateNo` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `certificateNo` (`certificateNo`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from t1 left outer join t2 on (t1.certificateNo = t2.certificateNo) where t2.certificateNo is null;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|    10839 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select count(1) from t1 left outer join t2 on (t1.certificateNo = t2.certificateNo) where t2.certificateNo is null;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index | NULL          | certificateNo | 35      | NULL | 35691 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref   | certificateNo | certificateNo | 99      | func |   138 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain select count(1) from t2 left outer join t1 on (t1.certificateNo = t2.certificateNo) where t1.certificateNo is null;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | index | NULL          | certificateNo | 99      | NULL | 27785 | Using index              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index | NULL          | certificateNo | 35      | NULL | 35691 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from t1 inner join t2  on (t1.certificateNo = t2.certificateNo) ;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|    21603 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.16 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from t1;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|    32442 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(1) from t2;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
|    26837 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The `CHARACTER SET` is different in the two tables.

Comment: yep. tested. If they have same character set it uses the ref in either case.

Comment: Good catch @Barmar, I only saw the charsets at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` syntax. And to take this a step further, I'd suggest adding unsigned int columns to both tables and join on those rather than joining on `varchar` columns.

Comment: @Barmar Yes I had noticed it before posting :-) but it still doesn't explain why does a key get used in one case and not in the other.

Comment: It must have to do with whether it can convert the character set and search for it in the index. Apparently that only works one way, not the other.